# Get object values returning from query

Tags: java

I have a query result which returns Object,

```
{startDate:2018-10-01 00:00:00.000, endDate:2018-10-31 00:00:00.000}
```

I want to get that start date and end date separately from that object.

note, I don't want to use return the query as class name object.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you

```
String query = "some query blah blah....";    
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    String startDate= rs.getString("startDate");
    String endDate= rs.getString("endDate");
}
```